# Spring cloud stream - support for rebalancing consumers with Kinesis

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

Does spring cloud stream support Kafka-like rebalancing for kinesis also? There has been a recent commit to the issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/issues/99

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no exact, Kafka-like behavior in the AWS Kinesis at all. In Kafka the rebalancing is performed on the broker side and all the consumers are notified about their own assignments.

What we have currently in the `KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` is some kind of leader election between shard consumers. But solution is not full yet with the automatic rebalancing when a new consumer is joined the group.

There is something like auto-rebalance in the Kinesis Client Library and already have a `KclMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`, but it is not release ready yet from the Spring Integration AWS perspective.

Comment: Thanks Artem Bilan.

Comment: For kafka binder setting autoRebalanceEnabled=true will take care of distributing partitions among consumers in the consumer group. For kinesis,  only static shard distribution is supported, if one of the consumer in the group is down, then corresponding partition is not consumed. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: That’s no. It is going to be picked up because all the consumers try to lock shards they are aware of.

Comment: And one more time: Kafka does rebalance on the server. We don’t have such a luxury with Kinesis

Comment: From the documentation KCL supports auto rebalance - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-record-processor-scaling.html. Spring Stream Kinesis binder is based on Spring AWS integration and Spring AWS integration is based on KCL. Is Spring cloud stream using some older version of KCL that does not support auto rebalance ? 
Thanks for previous replies. Appreciated.

Comment: I am Spring Integration AWS developer and believe me: it is not based on KCL. We have plans for that though, but it is not what we can talk already